# Calling javascript function with button and input from textbox

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, textbox

I have a textbox and button in my page. I have several sets of the below for different purpose.

```
<input type="text" id="new" name="new" value="1" />
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="compute(edit(xxx));" />
```

Upon clicking on the button, I want to call a javascript function which will take in the value input in the textbox. Now I am wondering how am I suppose to retrieve the value from the input 'new' and pass it the 'xxx' as argument?

Comment: Try `compute(edit(document.getElementById('new').value))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" onClick="compute(edit(document.getElementById('new').value))" />
```

This is how you handle it there in the HTML.

Else you can write the same code in javaScript.

```
function edit()
{
     x = document.getElementById('new').value;
     //use this X.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why you don't try this by Jquery it is to understand and easy to implement.

[`Jquery Documentation`](http://jquery.com/%E2%80%8E)

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
alert($('#new').val());// to get input text value
    $('#new').val('xxx');//to set input text value
});
```

your question Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/GqtcW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="compute(edit(document.getElementById('new').value));" />
```