# I need to find the longest word in a sentence using JS

Tags: javascript, html, count, return

I am having trouble getting my JS to return the longest word when I click on the button. I am not sure what in my JS code I am missing or have put incorrectly, but when I type in three words nothing is given back to me. I have pasted below both my JS and html codes.

***HTML:***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Longest Word</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/easy.css">      
    <script src="p3-longest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
         <h1>Longest Word</h1>

    </header>
<body>
    <form action="demo_form.asp" id="demo_form">
  Phrase:
  <input type="text" id="input1" name="LongestWord" placeholder="Put Phrase Here">
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Longest Word">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

***JS:***

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length ; i++) {
        if (longest < str[i].length) {
            longest = str[i].length;
            word = str[i];
        }
    }
    return word;
}

function init() {
    alert('count words');
    var countTag = document.getElementById('btn1');
    countTag.onclick = longestWord(string);
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216758/find-out-the-longest-word-from-a-sentence-javascript

Comment: Your JS is correct. However, it is not in any way connected to your HTML. There is nothing that says "when this button is pressed, do this".

Comment: My code doesn't work. I saw that question as well and couldn't figure out how to correct it

Comment: @Amadan could that be fixed with a "on.click" command? Or how can that be added? Thank You

Comment: To hook up the button and your code, [please consult this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205687/calling-javascript-function-with-button-and-input-from-textbox).

Comment: `$(...).on('click', ...)` is jQuery, and yes, this would be one way to do it. Plain JavaScript is with `document.getElementById(...).addEventListener('click', ...)`, or `.onclick = ...`. Another way is demonstrated in the link by Ken Y-N, but that one (putting JavaScript directly into `onclick="..."` attribute is discouraged by advanced users.

Comment: I tried that, and when clicked nothing happens. It says my string is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Phrase:
<input type="text" id="input1" name="LongestWord" placeholder="Put Phrase Here">
<br>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="get Longest Word">
<br/>
Longest Word: <span id='sp1'></span>
<script>                   
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
    var in1 = document.getElementById("input1");
    var sp1 = document.getElementById("sp1");
    btn.onclick = function(){
        var vals = in1.value.split(' ');
        var val = vals[0];
        vals.forEach(function(v){ if(v.length>val.length) val = v;});
        sp1.textContent = val;
    }
</script>
```

#### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v4w8qxft/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your button:

```
 onClick="alert(longestWord(document.getElementById('input1').value))"
```

It will take the value of input1 and send it to your longestWord-function. Then put up an alert-box with the return value from your function.

Comment: i tried that and it didn't work. Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1emm5odt/ , maybe that can help?

Comment: The onClick goes into the button like so: <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Longest Word" onclick="alert(longestWord(document.getElementById('input1').value))">

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything particularly wrong with your code ... except for the fact that "I don't see any code here that will ever 'give anything back to you!'"  **:-)**

Presumably, "`onload`", the `init()` function dutifully runs ... and setting `countTag.onclick` to whatever integer value `longestWord()` might return when given the *undefined* value of the non-declared non-variable `length`. *(Which is of no good use at all to `onclick`, which expects a function, not an integer...)*

None of which, even if it *did* work (which it doesn't ...), ever asks the digital computer to, by any means at all, "give anything back to you!"